# CSV(having extra quotes in field value) to array in ColdFusion

Tags: regex, csv, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, csvtoarray

I am converting a CSV file to array using [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/991-csvtoarray-coldfusion-udf-for-parsing-csv-data-files.htm) post. Everything was working fine. But I got a file which contains extra quotes in field values like:

`"bash: "shortcuts" are"` and

`"bash: \"shortcuts\" are"`.

So I tried replacing these quotes like this:

```
<cffile action="read" file="#filePath#" variable="csvContent">
<cfset csvContent = reReplace(csvContent, '(?:[^,\r\n])"(?:[^,\r\n])', '&quot;', 'ALL')>

<--- Then do the conversion --->
<cfset array = csvToArray(csv = csvContent)>
```

But the non capturing group is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Is there any other way to do this?

> Edit 1:

I also tried using `cfhttp` and got following error:

```
<cfhttp name="csvToQuery" method="get" url="#url#" />
```

> **Detail** : Verify the number of columns specified in the columns
> attribute and in the target file
>
> **Message** : Incorrect number of columns in row.
>
> **StackTrace** :
> coldfusion.tagext.net.HttpTag$InvalidColumnsException: Incorrect
> number of columns in row. at
> coldfusion.tagext.net.HttpTag.connHelper(HttpTag.java:1149) at
> coldfusion.tagext.net.HttpTag.doEndTag(HttpTag.java:1219) at
> cfmfhttp2ecfm308364137.runPage(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mfhttp.cfm:1) at
> coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244) at
> coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:446) at
> coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65) at
> coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:64) at
> coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:430)
> at
> coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
> at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
> at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112) at
> coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30) at
> coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at
> coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
> at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at
> coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58) at
> coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at
> coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at
> coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at
> coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219) at
> coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at
> coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
> at
> coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422)
> at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:199)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: If you use cfhttp to read your csv file you have a query object.  Depending on your final objective, this might be a more suitable approach.

Comment: @DanBracuk I also used that approach but I am getting error. I have added it in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Oh you won't be able to fix this sort of input by yourself so easily. Regular expressions will break your data even further.

Can you create a little script in Java to handle that? If you do, then use [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to read your CSV input and write it back with the correct quote escapes:

This is the only CSV parser that can handle broken quote escapes. Try this example:

```java
import com.univocity.parsers.csv;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String ... args){
        CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
        settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\r\n");
        settings.setParseUnescapedQuotes(true); // THIS IS IMPORTANT FOR YOU
        CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

        String line1 = "something,\"a quoted value \"with unescaped quotes\" can be parsed\", something\r\n";
        System.out.println("Input line: " + line1);

        String line2 = "\"after the newline \r\n you will find \" more stuff\r\n";
        System.out.println("Input line: " + line2);

        List<String[]> allInputLines = parser.parseAll(new StringReader(line1 + line2));

        System.out.println("===============\nParsed input values\n===============");
        int count = 0;
        for(String[] line : allInputLines){
            System.out.println("From line " + ++count + ":");
            for(String element : line){
                System.out.println("\t" + element);

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        //Let's write your output CSV
        StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
        CsvWriterSettings writerSettings = new CsvWriterSettings();
        writerSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\r\n");
        writerSettings.getFormat().setQuoteEscape('\\'); //it seems you are using backslash as quote escape
        writerSettings.getFormat().setCharToEscapeQuoteEscaping('\\'); //when your quote escape character is not the same as the quote character, you might need to escape the escape character as well
        writerSettings.setQuoteAllFields(true); //let's force quotes on all fields so whatever is parsing your input file has more  chance of doing it properly
        CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(output, writerSettings);

        for(String[] row : allInputLines){
            writer.writeRow(row);
        }
        writer.close();

        System.out.println("===============\nNicely formatted output\n===============");
        System.out.println(output.toString());

    }

}
```

This code will produce the following output (which can probably be read by your data import tool):

```java
Input line: something,"a quoted value "with unescaped quotes" can be parsed", something

Input line: "after the newline 
you will find " more stuff

===============
Parsed input values
===============
From line 1:
    something
    a quoted value "with unescaped quotes" can be parsed
    something

From line 2:
    after the newline 
you will find " more stuff


===============
Nicely formatted output
===============
"something","a quoted value \"with unescaped quotes\" can be parsed","something"

"after the newline 
 you will find \" more stuff"
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

**ColdFusion 10+ Example:**

1. Load the jar in your Application.cfc

   ```java
   this.javaSettings = { loadPaths: ["C:\path\to\univocity-parsers-1.5.6.jar" ]};
   ```
2. Create instances of the parser classes with createObject:

   ```java
   filePath = "c:\path\to\yourFile.csv";
   settings = createObject("java", "com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings").init();
   settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator(chr(13)& chr(10));
   settings.getFormat().setQuoteEscape("\");
   settings.setParseUnescapedQuotes(true); // THIS IS IMPORTANT FOR YOU
   parser = createObject("java", "com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser").init(settings);
   reader = createObject("java", "java.io.StringReader").init(fileRead(filePath));
   arrayOfLines = parser.parseAll(reader);

   // display results
   counter = 1;
   for (line in arrayOfLines) {
       writeOutput("<br>From line "& (counter++) & ":");
       for (element in line) {
          writeOutput("<br>"& element);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Nice. Hope you do not mind, but since CF runs on top of java, I added a small translation rather than posting a separate answer that just repeats yours. Tested with CF11. One small change, I needed to add `settings.getFormat().setQuoteEscape("\");` to handle the escaping in their second example. If you do not like the changes, feel free to roll it back.